# Pros and cons of each key generation strategy in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm migrating a SQL database of a web application to RavenDB and my team is trying to define what key generation strategy is the best for us.
The main discussion point is whether we use natural keys or surrogate keys. So I would like to know the pros and cons of each strategy in RavenDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The recommended solution is to let RavenDB handles them for you.
It will generate things like "items/2", etc.
To start with, those are plenty good enough, human readable and easy to generate efficiently.

You can also do things like "users/ayende", but I would wait for that until you have more experience with RavenDB.

Finally, for advance stuff, you have keys such as "customers/1234/orders/8234" which opens up some really nice option for advanced scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I choose a surrogate key, like the hilo strategy, it would be possible to create URLs using a more representative key, like "http://example.com/users/ayende", to point to a document "users/1"? Or in this case, a natural key would be more appropriate?

Comment: @peflorencio not directly, it would break your links. If you use hilo, you'll have to translate your lookups between url-friendly and data access (e.g. converts `users-1` to `users/1`. What I've been doing is using a combination of the two ideas which is to use the collection name with the natural key and a colon (e.g. `foo:some-key-here`). You'll wanna make sure that key is an attribute on the document and enforced unique. I don't know of other implications but I haven't had issues yet.

Comment: The reason I chose to do that was to simplify the process of updating documents with references to other documents. I felt like it would make graphing simpler too /shrug

Answer (score 0):

If you build too much logic in your keys you may regret it later unless you know your problem domain well.  We do a fair amount of RavenDB work in PHP, since there is no client.  We prototype in C# then usually follow what the client creates.  Sometimes the auto-pluralization's come out funny like People might be Peoples.  This normally does not matter unless you are hitting RavenDB directly from Javascript.  Then the only downfall is friends may question your English skills.